# Memory saving in multi-dimentional array

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Hi i need a multidimentional array to store big number but i am getting heap space error. I have 4gb ram.

```
double array[][] = new double[100000][100000]
```

I know it would need a lot of memory, can any one help me tackling this issue? Thanks for helping

Comment: `100000*100000*8` bytes of data (or `*64` bits). No I do not think anyone here can help you tackle the issue. Tell us why you need *that* large array. *PS. It is roughly 72 GB of data.*

Comment: What do you mean when you say "to store big number"? Is your data actually filling 100,000 rows and columns of an array?

Comment: You'll need a 64-bit JVM, and roughly 74GiB of RAM. (But swap space also counts as RAM here, but the swap space limit is probably lower than that)

Comment: Looks like you need to download more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sparse (more empty array cells than filled ones), you could look at using a hash map instead.

For the hash map, use the index of the array as the key.

example:

```
{ 23: 'foo', 23945: 'bar' }
```

this will be much more memory efficient!

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need that much memory, you will need at minimum 100000*100000*8 B, or 80 GB of RAM (plus whatever overhead there is for the array organization itself). I will go as far as to say that you probably cannot work with that much data in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way you'll be able to have an array that big is to write the parts of the array that aren't in use at a given moment in time out to disk. This will take some work to do though because you have to track where you are in the array to push and pull the array's data on the disk.